# accessing objects in an array Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, accessor

I am having trouble understanding how to set and get objects in an array. Please keep it basic/simple; I am a beginner.
I cannot use a list as I am not there yet in my java class. We are supposed to use regular arrays.

I am building a program that creates solar system objects and puts planet objects in the solar system object array. I have to be able to insert the planet by index as well as get it by index.

Getting regular object info was simple but once arrays were added. It got tough. I understand better when I can comprehend how and why something works. Here is my code. Many thanks in advance!

Planet Class

```
public class Planet {

    // private fields
    private String planetName;
    private int numMoons;


    // param constructor
    public Planet(String n, int m){
        planetName = n;
        numMoons = m;

    }

    public String toString(){
        return planetName + " " + numMoons;
    }



    public void setPlanetName(String n){
        this.planetName = n;

    }

    public String getPlanetName(){
        return planetName;

    }

    public void setNumMoons(int m){
        this.numMoons = m;

    }

    public int getNumMoons(){
        return numMoons;

    }
}
```

Here is the SolarSystem class

```
package project03;

public class SolarSystem {

    private String solarSystemName;
    private Planet[] allPlanets = new Planet[8];
    private int numPlanets;

    public SolarSystem(String ss, int np){
        solarSystemName = ss;
        numPlanets = np;


    }

    public void setSolarSystemName(String ss){
        solarSystemName = ss;

    }

    public String getSolarSystemName(){
        return solarSystemName;
    }

    /*public void setAllPlanets(String ss){
        solarSystemName = ss;

    }

    public String getSolarSystemName(){
        return solarSystemName;
    }
*/

}
```

Finally here is my driver class that houses the main method

```
package project03;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        // creates planet object
        Planet Mercury = new Planet("Mercury", 0);
        Planet Venus = new Planet("Venus", 0);
        Planet Earth = new Planet("Earth", 1);
        Planet Mars = new Planet("Mars", 2);
        Planet Jupiter = new Planet("Jupiter", 67);
        Planet Saturn = new Planet("Saturn", 62);
        Planet Uranus = new Planet("Uranus", 27);
        Planet Neptune = new Planet("Neptune", 14);



        SolarSystem ourSolarSystem = new SolarSystem("Sol-System", 8);

        System.out.println("Planet name is : " + ourSolarSystem.getSolarSystemName());
        //System.out.println("Moon number is :" + Mercury.getNumMoons());
    }



}
```

Comment: You should take a look at this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: I appreciate the link. I just read it but it does not mention anything as far as my question goes. I did learn a bit about array basics however.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a couple of methods from your `SolarSystem` class

```
public void setPlanet (Planet planet, int pos) {
   allPlanets [pos] = planet;  // pos is zero based
}

public Planet getPlanet (int pos) {
   return allPlanets [pos];  // pos is zero based
}
```

Then you can use it as

```
ourSolarSystem.setPlanet (Mercury, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add methods in your solar system class to add objects to the internal array.

to populate an array , you need 2 things
1. Size
2. Elements.

Your solar system class has provisions for none at this point. Size is hardcoded to 8, which is fine for this example, ideally it should be passed in constructor while creating a solar system.
Ignoring that for a moment, you should add method in the class to add a planet.

Since this is for your learning, I am not adding exact code, just algorithm

```
public void addPlanet(Planet p, int pos){
//check pos is less than array size
// add planet to the index pos if pos is less than size.
}
```

You could also create an array outside and add it to the solar planet

```
public void addPlanets(Planet[] planetArray){
// replace current planet array with the array passed in input
}
```

The array outside can be created easily

```
Planet[] planetArray = new Planet[8];
planetArray[0] = Mercury ;

// and so on.
```